# Error while doing split in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look at the following piece of code:

```
var arr = [ ];
$('a').filter(function () {
            var hf = this.href;
            if(hf.indexOf('www.') === 0)
                 hf = hf.slice(4);
            hf = this.href.split('/')[2];
            hf = hf.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
            $.inArray(hf, arr) == -1;
    })
```

I receive an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

at the following line:

```
hf = hf.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
```

Any idea why and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you check/output the content of hf? Does it contain what you expect (www. and / and dots)?

Comment: For http:// domainname it doesn't but for anything starting with www it does. That's why I am doing if(hf.indexOf('www.') === 0)

Comment: I tried running the code, but 'arr' is undefined. Is there some additional JavaScript code you could post with the html also?

Comment: I have added arr to the code.

Comment: What's $.inArray(hf, arr) == -1; meant to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

Let's see:

```js
// `this` is an <a> element
var hf = this.href;
// `hf` is a string
hf = this.href.split('/')[2];
// `hf` may be a string (if it had at least two `/`), or undefined
```

So the problem is that you have some anchor whose [serialized URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/url/#concept-url-serializer) contains less than 2 `/`. Usually that's not the case (e.g. when a relative URL is serialized, `//` is appended), but it's possible. For example:

```html
<a href="foobar:"></a>
```

If you want to obtain the host or the hostname, use the [`host`](http://www.w3.org/TR/url/#dom-urlutils-host) or the [`hostname`](http://www.w3.org/TR/url/#dom-urlutils-hostname) properties.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a');
console.log(a.host);     // "foo.bar.com:123"
console.log(a.hostname); // "foo.bar.com"
```

```html
<a href="http://foo.bar.com:123/path/file.htm"></a>
```

In case of `<a href="foobar:"></a>`, both `host` and `hostname` will return the empty string, without throwing any error.

So your code should be like

```js
var hf = this.hostname.split('.'); /* or `host` */
if(hf[0] == 'www')
    hf.shift();
hf = hf.slice(-2).join('.');
```

Comment: yes your code is much better than mine. Thanks. Why have you been downvoted

Comment: @user1089173 Also note removing 'www' may not be necessary because of `slice(-2)`. But keep it if you want to strip it in 'www.com'.

Answer (score -1):

I ran the code with assumed anchor tag using http://www.yahoo.com and I do not get any errors.

```js
var arr = [ ];
$('a').filter(function () {
            var hf = this.href;
            if(hf.indexOf('www.') === 0)
                 hf = hf.slice(4);
            hf = this.href.split('/')[2];
            hf = hf.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
            console.log('hf: ', hf);
            $.inArray(hf, arr) == -1;
    })
```

```html
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">link</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r330k6sh/

There must be something going on with your html anchor or http vs https possibly.

Comment: That one works for me too without any errors on that same jsfiddle I linked. Just need to update the url in the html section with your link to see it working.

Comment: If you are getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined, chances are that the logic in your code is not always producing a string when calling the line of code:

hf = hf.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');

Comment: Parsing urls manually can be tricky because there are a variety of formats to take into account. I would recommend a plugin to do this for you.

https://plugins.jquery.com/url/